# Working with opaque types (Char and Long)

Tags: scala.js

I'm trying to export a Scala implementation of an algorithm for use in JavaScript.  I'm using `@JSExport`. The algorithm works with Scala `Char` and `Long` values which are marked as *opaque* in the [interoperability guide](http://www.scala-js.org/doc/js-interoperability.html#type-correspondance).

I'd like to know (a) what this means; and (b) what the recommendation is for dealing with this.

I presume it means I should avoid `Char` and `Long` and work with `String` plus a run-time check on length (or perhaps use a shapeless `Sized` collection) and `Int` instead.

But other ideas welcome.

*More detail...*

The kind of code I'm looking at is:

```
@JSExport("Foo")
class Foo(val x: Int) {
  @JSExport("add")
  def add(n: Int): Int = x+n
}
```

...which works just as expected: `new Foo(1).add(2)` produces `3`.

Replacing the types with `Long` the same call reports: 
`java.lang.ClassCastException: 1 is not an instance of scala.scalajs.runtime.RuntimeLong` (and something similar with methods that take and return `Char`).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Being opaque means that

- There is no corresponding JavaScript type
- There is no way to *create* a value of that type from JavaScript (except if there is an `@JSExport`ed constructor)
- There is no way of *manipulating* a value of that type (other than calling `@JSExport`ed methods and fields)

It is still possible to receive a value of that type from Scala.js code, pass it around, and give it back to Scala.js code. It is also always possible to call `.toString()`, because `java.lang.Object.toString()` is `@JSExport`ed. Besides `toString()`, neither `Char` nor `Long` export anything, so you can't do anything else with them.

Hence, as you have experienced, a JavaScript `1` cannot be used as a Scala.js `Long`, because it's not of the right type. Neither is `'a'` a valid `Char` (but it's a valid `String`).

Therefore, as you have inferred yourself, you must indeed avoid opaque types, and use other types instead if you need to create/manipulate them from JavaScript. The Scala.js side can convert back and forth using the standard tools in the language, such as `someChar.toInt` and `someInt.toChar`.

The choice of which type is best depends on your application. For `Char`, it could be `Int` or `String`. For `Long`, it could be `String`, a pair of `Int`s, or possibly even `Double` if the possible values never use more than 52 bits of precision.