# Typed façade for JS library in Scala.js

Tags: scala, scala.js

I am trying to write a typed façade for my library [Paths.js](https://github.com/andreaferretti/paths-js), following [the official guide](http://www.scala-js.org/doc/calling-javascript.html).

What I would like to be able to translate is a call like the following:

```
var Polygon = require('paths-js/Polygon');
var polygon = Polygon({
  points: [[1, 3], [2, 5], [3, 4], [2, 0]],
  closed: true
});
```

into

```
val polygon = Polygon(points = List((1, 3), (2, 5), (5, 6)), closed = true)
```

but I am not sure what I need to do to get to this point.

What I have done is something like the following

```
type Point = (Number, Number)
trait PolygonOpt {
  val points: Array[Point]
  val closed: Boolean
}
@JSName("paths.Polygon")
object Polygon extends js.Object {
  def apply(options: PolygonOpt): Shape = js.native
}
```

Then, I can invoke it like

```
class Opt extends PolygonOpt {
  val points: Array[Point] = Array((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6))
  val closed = true
}
val opts = new Opt
val poly = Polygon(opts)
```

I have a few doubts on this:

- I am at a point where everything compiles, but the resulting javascript fails at the point of invocation. I believe that this is because I am passing an instance of `PolygonOpt`, while the runtime expects a javascript object literal
- is the definition of `Point` translated into a js array with two components?
- I would like to be able to overload `Polygon.apply` like `def apply(points: Seq[Point], closed: Boolean): Shape`, but scala.js does not let me write method implementation inside `Polygon` since it extends `js.Object`

Moreover, I have both a version of my library using common.js (which is split into several files, one for each component) and another one which can be used as a single `<script>` tag, putting everything under the namespace `paths` (which is the one I am using right now).

Which one works better for a Scala.js wrapper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, make sure to read the [JS interop doc](http://www.scala-js.org/doc/js-interoperability.html), including the [calling JavaScript guide](http://www.scala-js.org/doc/calling-javascript.html). I think you did so already, because you already have something reasonable. But you should pay particular attention to the parts that say that Scala types and JavaScript types are completely unrelated unless explicitly mentioned.

So, an `Int` is a proper JS `number` (in the range of an int). But an `Array[Point]` has nothing to do with a JavaScript array. A `Tuple2` (such as `(1, 3)`) even less so. So:

> Is the definition of `Point` translated into a js array with two components?

No, it is not. As such, it is completely incomprehensible to JavaScript. It is [opaque](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27821841/working-with-opaque-types-char-and-long).

Worse, a `PolygonOpt`, since it does not extend `js.Object`, is completely opaque as well from JavaScript, which explains why you cannot see the fields `points` and `closed`.

The first thing to do is to type accurately, with JavaScript-understandable types (extending `js.Object`), your JS API. In this case, it would look like this:

```
type JSPoint = js.Array[Int] // or Double

trait PolygonOpts extends js.Object {
  val points: js.Array[JSPoint] = js.native
  val closed: Boolean = js.native
}

@JSName("paths.Polygon")
object Polygon extends js.Object {
  def apply(options: PolygonOpt): Shape = js.native
}
```

Now, the thing is that it is not really easy to *create* an instance of `PolygonOpts`. For this refer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23663059/what-is-the-suggested-way-to-instantiate-a-js-object-for-api-wrappers):

```
object PolygonOpts {
  def apply(points: js.Array[JSPoint], closed: Boolean): PolygonOpts = {
    js.Dynamic.literal(
        points = points,
        closed = closed
    ).asInstanceOf[PolygonOpts]
  }
}
```

Finally, you can expose the Scala-esque API you wanted in the first place with implicit extensions:

```
import js.JSConverters._

object PolygonImplicits {
  implicit class PolygonObjOps(val self: Polygon.type) extends AnyVal {
    def apply(points: List[(Int, Int)], closed: Boolean): Shape = {
      val jsPoints =
        for ((x, y) <- points.toJSArray)
          yield js.Array(x, y)
      Polygon(PolygonOpts(jsPoints, closed))
    }
  }
}
```

Implicit extensions are the way to write Scala methods that appear to be available on objects extending `js.Object`, since, as you discovered, you cannot actually implement methods *inside* a `js.Object`.

Comment: Thank you very much! It looks like a quite common case (converting a function that takes an object literal to a function that takes named arguments) requires lots of boilerplate.... I wonder if it would be worth the main to write a macro for this

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot have a method in an implicit extension called apply, since that already exists on the original object, and the compiler does not look for an implicit conversion. I will probably just drop the method taking `PolygonOpts` and expose the more scalaesque interface. A little unfortunate, though, since it will be harder to pass an instance of `PolygonOpts` coming from the javascript side, but that should not happen too often