# Interop between js and scala functions in Scala.js

Tags: scala, scala.js

I am trying to write a typed façade for my library [Paths.js](https://github.com/andreaferretti/paths-js), following the [official guide](http://www.scala-js.org/doc/calling-javascript.html).

Following advice from Sebastien in [Typed façade for JS library in Scala.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28558820), I was able to flesh out part of the API. What I am now missing is a way to deal with a conversion function which is exposed in the API. Basically, the library lets you write something like

```
var pie = Pie({
  data: [
    { name: 'Italy', population: 59859996 },
    { name: 'Mexico', population: 118395054 },
    { name: 'France', population: 65806000 }
  ],
  accessor: function(x) { return x.population; },
  center: [20, 15],
  r: 30,
  R: 50
});
```

The idea is that - to simplify client code - the library does not require you to transform your data to a form that is amenable to plotting. Rather, you can provide a list of data in the form that you see fit, and then pass an `accessor` function to extract a number from the raw datum. This also makes it easier to associate path objects with the original datum.

The signature that I would like to expose on the Scala side would look like this:

```
object Pie {
  type Point = (Double, Double)
  def apply(data: Seq[A],
    accessor: A => Double,
    center: Point, r: Double, R: Double)
}
```

I am trying to convert `accessor`, which has type `A => Double` to something like `js.Function1[js.Any, Double]`, and my attempt looks like (using the implicit conversion between `Function1` and `js.Function1`)

```
val f: js.Any => Double = x => x match {
  case _: A => accessor(x)
  case _ => ???
}
```

This gives me a warning `abstract type pattern A is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure`.

What would be a better way to translate this API?

Comment: Why do you want `js.Function1[js.Any, Double]`? Isn't `js.Function1[A, Double]` what you want. Then the `A => Double` would simply convert implicitly to `js.Function1[A, Double]`.

Comment: Yes, I actually want `js.Function1[A, Double]`. But the underlying native method does not know about types. Can we have polymorphic methods declared as native?

Comment: I have tried and I found no problem so far in defining a polymorphic trait that extends `js.Object`, having polymorphic native methods. Can this have unintended side-effects?

Comment: No that's meant to work. It is even documented somewhere in [the doc](http://www.scala-js.org/doc/calling-javascript.html): "JS traits and their methods can have type parameters, abstract type members and type aliases, without restriction compared to Scala's type system."

Comment: Great! I am almost done :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resume the discussion in the comments:

Using a `js.Function1[A, Double]` is perfectly valid and reasonable in this case.

As @sjrd cites from the [Scala.js doc](http://www.scala-js.org/doc/calling-javascript.html):

> JS traits and their methods can have type parameters, abstract type members and type aliases, without restriction compared to Scala's type system.